# no errors thrown, python creates blank file, not sure how to troubleshoot

Tags: python

I'm able to use the read command and use the contents of a file, but I am having issues writing to a file.

I've tried both 'w' and 'a' with the same results.  It always creates the target file, but it is empty (zero bytes).

```
FILE_TARGET = ("Data\AlbumUpdates.txt")
z=open(FILE_TARGET,"a")

z.write("Hello")
z.write("goodybye")
z.write("one")
z.write("two")
z.write("three")
z.flush
z.close
```

Any help is appreciated... Is there any way to get a return code back from the write command?

Comment: You don't need `flush` but you are not actually closing the file. Do `z.close()` instead.

Comment: But python should close the file on exit anyway. This problem does not reproduce on linux and I think it should work on windows too.

Comment: How are you running this? If from a GUI, you may be in a different directory than you think. What does `import os;print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))` say?

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the correct output file? You used a relative path and the path is relative to the current working directory and that doesn't have to be the same directory where the script is.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer.  Some clarification.  1) running from the GUI 2) I am definitely checking the correct file location because the file gets re-created after I delete it and run the code again.  3) I did execute the getcwd code you provided and it matches the expected location.

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way to read / write to a file is by using the `with`statement.  Although you can explicitly call open and close as in your example. flush is not needed.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

This will close the file automatically for you.

You should use `os.path`to create paths to files /directories which will avoid any errors.

You can assign the write to a variable and it will return the number of characters of what was written.

You can check this against the length of the word if you assign it first or iterate over a list for example.

```
import os.path

FILE_TARGET = os.path.join("Data", "AlbumUpdates.txt") # safely create the path.

# Use the with context to automatically close the file gracefully
with open(FILE_TARGET,"a") as z:

    words = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "One", "Two", "Three"] # alist to iterate over, it will assign each word to a variable so you can check its length.

    for w in words:
        r = z.write(w) # assign the write to a variable.  It will return the length it wrote.
        print(r == len(w)) # Check that what has written matches what was passed.
```

Comment: Thanks All, I'm  not really sure why my original code didn't work right.  I did switch to a 'with' and also did the compare to make sure the output matches what was expected.